# Algorithm for subdividing html-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write a module that automatically subdivides  div-elements, given some initial parameters.

I've prepared the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/386er/z54x2vuy/16/).

What I am doing at the moment is:

1. Setting the width and height of the parent element.
2. Setting the child elements to float left and assigning percentual width and height to them, based on the specified parameters.

```
that.createDivisionData = function(paramObj) {

    var 
        numOfDivisions = paramObj.divisions,
        widthTop = paramObj.widthTop,
        heightTop = paramObj.heightTop,
        widthBottom = paramObj.widthBottom,
        widthBlock = paramObj.blockWidth,
        heightBlock = paramObj.blockHeight,
        data = [];

    for ( var i = 1; i <= numOfDivisions; i++) {
        var divisionObj = {};
        if (i < 3) {
            divisionObj.widthPerc = i % 2 ? widthTop + '%' : (100 - widthTop) + '%';
            divisionObj.width = i % 2 ? widthTop * widthBlock / 100 : (100 - widthTop) * widthBlock / 100;
            divisionObj.heightPerc = heightTop + '%';
            divisionObj.height = heightBlock * heightTop / 100;
        } else {
            divisionObj.widthPerc =  i % 2 ? widthBottom + '%' : (100 - widthBottom) + '%';
            divisionObj.width =  i % 2 ? widthBottom * widthBlock / 100 : (100 - widthBottom) * widthBlock / 100;
            divisionObj.heightPerc = (100 - heightTop) + '%';
            divisionObj.height = (100 - heightTop) * heightBlock / 100;
        }
        data.push(divisionObj);
    }        
    return data;
};
```

The way I am doing it at the moment actually works. But it feels somehow wrong, dirty, unfinished, you name it. I know this is a subjective question, but maybe someone has an idea. How can I do this in a cleaner way?

Comment: `if (i < 3) { ...`    What is different about those first two items versus the rest?

Comment: The first two items will have the heightTop value assigned  as their height, whereas the following items will get the inverted heightTop value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of what you are doing is repeated code so you should DRY it out.  For instance, `widthPerc` is the same code **except** for the values of `widthTop` and `widthBottom`. We can also simply all of our checks by setting them up as `var`s.  So that could be re-written like this:

```
var isFirstTwo = !!( i < 3 ); // go ahead and just eval once
var isEven = !!( i % 2 ); // go ahead and just evalonce

//which width value do we want?
var widthDir = ( isFirstTwo ) ? widthTop : widthBottom;
//is it an even number?
widthDir = ( isEven ) ? widthDir : 100 - widthDir;
widthBlock = widthDir * widthBlock / 100;  

divisionObj.widthPerc = widthDir +'%';
divisionObj.width = widthBlock;
```

This reduces a lot of your code.  You could follow a similar technique for height (it's actually easier than width).

```
var heightTop = ( isEven ) ? heightTop : (100 - heightTop);
var heightBlock =  heightBlock * heightTop / 100
divisionObj.heightPerc = heightTop + '%';
divisionObj.height = heightBlock;
```

Hope that helps. I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z54x2vuy/17/). Let me know if you have questions or comments.

Comment: I am leaving for the day but I will check back tomorrow morning.